# How to install windows application in Ubuntu

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation

Is it possible to install windows application on **Ubuntu**.
We want to install windows application on Ubuntu since Ubuntu is a free software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) for the same.

Comment: thank you, I already have the [wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine) @Prashanth kumar

Answer (score 1):

used [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/) is a compatibility layer capable of running Windows applications on several POSIX-compliant operating systems, such as Linux, macOS, & BSD.